# display empty fields when missing data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have this JSON:

```
 "person": [
        {
            "id": 161,
            "description": null,
            "personDetails": [
                {
                    "id": 161,
                    "codiceCap": "021",
                    "descrizioneComune": "ROMA",
                    "descrizioneNazione": "ITALIA",
                    "indirizzo": "V.LE EUROPA",
                    "indirizzoEmail": null,
                    "numeroTelefono1": null,
                    "tipologiaDetail": "AS"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

For this JSON I have crated a form in HTML that display all those data.

In this JSON missing but I have 2 diffrent tipologiaIndirizzo, AS and SA.

For this situation I want to display always all field in HTML nad when one tipologiaIndirizzo missing in JSON. In this case I want to display empty fileds.

I'm trying this function, but I have error because tipologiaIndirizzo SA missing.

```
   model.personDetails.forEach((details) => {
                switch(details.tipologiaDetail) { 
                    case TipiPersonConstants.tipologiaDetail_AS: { 
                        this.detailsAS = details;
                        break; 
                    } 
                    case TipiPersonConstants.tipologiaDetail_ST: { 
                        this.detailsST =  details; 
                       break; 
                    } 
                    default: { 
                       this.detailsDefault = details;
                       break; 
                    } 
                 } 
             });
```

I need to do: To display all fields for 2 topologies, and when one topologies missing. In the case when one tipologie missing, should display empty fields.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. If I'm correctly understood, do you want to display the field even if in the JSON there isn't the property?

Comment: Yes, I want to display the fields even if in the JSON isn't the "tipologiaIndirizzo" property

Comment: I suggest you create a different class with the property that you want to display. Basically having an interface for the response and a class (if you need some logic on it) for the form